# Eclipse Maven dependency cannot be resolved to a type

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

Maven project dependencies are added and jars are downloaded also classes could be seen but in code it is saying "KafkaConsumer cannot be resolved to a type". 
I restarted the Eclipse.Did clean the project. Maven update project is done.But no option is working. Below is the image from the eclipse.

[image]

**Eclipse:**

```
Eclipse Java EE IDE for Web Developers.
Version: Neon.3 Release (4.6.3)
Build id: 20170314-1500
```

**pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>Apache.Kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>Apache.Kafka</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>Apache.Kafka</name>



    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <jdk.version>1.8</jdk.version>
        <jre.version>1.8</jre.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <version>0.10.1.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: Down voter pls comment1

Comment: Add code as text not as an Image, also add the pom.xml

Comment: How come that gives -1 I dont understand, this is related to the tool not code I believe.

Comment: @Jens pls check updated the pom.xml thanks for the reply.

Comment: For me it works fine. Can you try a "Organize Imports"?

Comment: are you sure your eclipse project is pointing to a jdk and not a jre?

Comment: @David Why OP should get These error message if he use an jre?

Comment: Have you tried a `mvn compile` using the console to see if the problem is related to Eclipse or not?

Answer (score 0):

This one worked for me in a project I did a few months ago.

I added all imports I needed, not the wildcard

```
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerConfig;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.ConsumerRecords;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer;

//Here you define the props and topics

KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]> consumer = new KafkaConsumer<String, byte[]>(props);
```

And I was using this other version:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
    <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
    <version>0.9.0.1</version>
</dependency>
```

However I suspect the problem is not in the dependency version.

Comment: This is not answer!

Comment: Have you tried to write the imports separated and the KafkaConsumer in this way? If so and doesnt work, it must be an issue with the IDE

Comment: Yes it says as The import org.apache.kafka.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer cannot be resolved

Comment: Ok let me open my project and compare with what you have show in the image. Maybe I will find something

Comment: I have everything like you, the only difference is with the KafkaConsumer version. I tried yours and the imports works fine after updating the project (Alt F5). It must be an issue with the IDE.  I will keep trying at home however if you prefer to delete the question, due the downvote someone cast on you, I will delete the answer

Comment: Which version you have pls tell me

Comment: Spring Tool Suit: 3.8.2
 And for the dependency I was using 0.9.0.1